# (Android Xamarin) Get Resource string value instead of int

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin

Im just starting to create a simple android app with the use of Xamarin using VS2012.
I know there is a type of Resource just for strings.
In my resource folder, i have an xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <string name="RecordsTable">records</string>
   <string name="ProjectTable">projects</string>
   <string name="ActivitiesTable">activities</string>
</resources>
```

In my code, I want to use the values of those resources like:

```
string recordTable = Resource.String.RecordsTable; //error, data type incompatibility
```

I know that  `Resource.String.<key>` returns an integer so I cant use the code above.
I am hoping that `recordTable` variable will have a value of `records`.

Is there a way I can use the value of those resource string for my code's string variables?

Comment: Just get the `int`, and then convert it to a `String`?

Comment: sorry, i cant understand what you are proposing.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

try it as using [Resources.GetString](http://docs.mono-android.net/?link=M%3aAndroid.Content.Res.Resources.GetString%28int%29#) for getting string from string Resources

```
Context context = this;
// Get the Resources object from our context
Android.Content.Res.Resources res = context.Resources;
// Get the string resource, like above.
string recordTable = res.GetString(Resource.String.RecordsTable);
```

Comment: hmm, i cant see the GetString method. And to be able to use the Resources object, i need to add the Android.Content.Res namespace.

Comment: @eaon21 : yes see [Resources.GetString](http://docs.mono-android.net/?link=M%3aAndroid.Content.Res.Resources.GetString%28int%29#)

Comment: I saw it! thanks.. however, i used Resources.System.GetString(id)...
Resources.GetString does not exist :(

Comment: @eaon21 : depend on how you are calling getString method

Comment: I think the reason why i did not see Resources.GetString() is because im coding using C#. I guess you have to use Resources.System.GetString() in C# instead.

Comment: is there any way to set resource programaticaly ?

Answer (score 13):

It's worth noting that you do **not** need to create an instance of `Resources` to access the resource table. This works equally well:

```
using Android.App;

public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    void SomeMethod()
    {
        string str = GetString(Resource.String.your_resource_id);
    }
}
```

`GetString()`, used this way, is a method defined on the abstract `Context` class. You can also use this version:

```
using Android.App;

public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    void SomeMethod()
    {
        string str = Resources.GetString(Resource.String.your_resource_id);
    }
}
```

`Resources`, used this way, is a read-only property on the `ContextWrapper` class, which `Activity` inherits from the `ContextThemeWrapper` class.

Answer (score 3):

If you're not in an activity or another context, you should get the context and use it to get the Resources and PackageName, as the following example:

```
int resID = context.Resources.GetIdentifier(listEntryContact.DetailImage.ImageName, "drawable", context.PackageName);
imageView.SetImageResource(resID);
```

Answer (score -5):

```
int int_recordTable = Resource.String.RecordsTable;

String recordTable = (String.valueOf(int_recordTable)); //no more errors
```

Get the`int`, then change it to a `String`

Comment: Since the OP is using Xamarin he is probably coding in .Net, not Java. Also I do not think he just wants to convert an int to a String