# Databinding with a localizable format string

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I'm making an Android app in Xamarin using MvvmCross.

My UI has a search field and a button. I want the button to reflect whatever is in the search field. So if the search field has `Alamo Drafthouse`, I want the button to say `Create "Alamo Drafthouse" Venue`, however the `Create "x" Venue` string should come from the `strings.xml` file so that it can be localized.

My current plan of attack is to create a ValueConverter that takes the search term and does the formatting, using the ConvertParameter to specify the ID of the string resource, so I'd be able to do something like this:

```
<Button local:MvxBind="Text SearchTerm, Converter=FormatResource, ConvertParameter='create_view'" />
```

where `create_view` is a string resource defined in `strings.xml`.

I thought I should ask whether there is a better way to do this. Is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the template string to come from `strings.xml` (from Android project, not from the Core/PCL project), you may create your own converter named `FormatResourceConverter`.

```
 public class FormatResourceConverter: IMvxValueConverter
 {
     public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
     {
         //value would be your draft house
         //parameter would be a name of your string in strings.xml
         var stringValue = ... //get your string from Android string resources 
         return String.Format(stringValue, value);    
     }

     public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
     {
         throw new NotImplementedException();
     }
 }
```

[Here is a simple answer how to get string from Android resources in Xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15897157/883738).